# In arcmap how to modify time value in editor tracking fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, tracking, timeslider

In my map, I have several layers enable editor tracking, but the time zone is not the same as our location time zone (GMT +8). When I try to use time slider to modify the time, I find the time slider is disabled.

I want to check how to modify the time value in the editor tracking fields. If use time slide, how can I enable time slider?

I am using arcmap 10.2.2.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. To enable the Time Slider, you must have Time enabled on one or more layers in the map document (there is a Time tab on the layer properties). The Time Slider *displays* information by time, it does not modify values. It is capable of [automatically converting between time zones](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005z0000001m000000). However if you're looking to actually change the values, that's more a field calculation.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the information. I tried to check "enable time on this layer", and after that I created a new feature on the layer, but the time value (created_date and last_edited_date) still follow the UTC time zone, not the UTC + 8 as wanted.

Comment: Hi all, I have found the reason - I need to set the editor tracking time zone to the database time zone. The steps have mentioned in this link: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/62920

Comment: I would suggest you go ahead and post that as an answer and accept it. It's [ok to answer your own question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and even accept that answer, though there are some waiting periods to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the reason - I need to set the editor tracking time zone to the database time zone. The steps have mentioned in this link: https://geonet.esri.com/login.jspa

Comment: what are the exact link that you mention? i can't get in

Answer (score 0):

Was going to write long answer on how to solve this issue but I think [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/enable-editor-tracking.htm), and [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/enabling-editor-tracking.htm) will do a better job explaining if its not obvious(and no Geonet Login).