# How to adjust the Record Dates field in ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, editing, tracking, standard-license-level

When I use the Editor Tracking in polygon layer, the Date time that been created is not true:

[image]

and my real time was:

[image]

I read:

1. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/enabling-editor-tracking.htm
2. [In arcmap how to modify time value in editor tracking fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115771/in-arcmap-how-to-modify-time-value-in-editor-tracking-fields)

but didn't understand how to change the Record Dates field in the Editor Tracking tool in the data management tools-any time,after I add the layer to the tool, the Record Dates option is blocked to only the UTC option:

[image]

I also worked on another polygon layer that don't have ant fields of Editor Tracking, and it still doesn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change from UTC to database time you'll need to disable Editor Tracking, then re-enable it, choosing database time rather than UTC.

Using the similar process as in your other question - [Automatically adding date to attribute table in ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203906/automatically-adding-date-to-attribute-table-in-arcgis-10-3-1-for-desktop) - you can select Disable Editor Tracking, and then again to select Enable Editor Tracking.  When you enable you can change your selection.